# Why query deos not fetching the result however there are rows?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch the records from two tables.

1 - tokens
2 - transactions

In both tables there is same column `user_id` and `tokens` table has `transaction_id`. I am trying to get all transactions which has relation with `token`. I am trying following

```
$EarnedData = Token::whereIn('user_id', $descendants)
    ->whereHas('transaction', function($q){
            $q->where('custom', '!=', 'BB')->orWhereNull('custom');
    })->sum('amount');
```

After debugging it, I got raw query from above script which is following

```
    select sum(`amount`) as aggregate from `tokens` 
    where 
    `user_id` in (15, 49, 58,117, 119, 120, 130, 13) 
    and exists 
    (select * from `transactions` where `tokens`.`transaction_id` = `transactions`.`id`
    and (`custom` != 'BONUS' or `custom` is null))
```

When I execute the query I got `NULL`, can someone kindly guide me why query does not getting the record. I would like to appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Because you never `->get();` the results! The `$earnedData` variable now contains the parsed query, seeing as you never executed it.

```
$earnedData = Token::whereIn('user_id', $descendants)
    ->whereHas('transaction', function($q) {
        $q->where('custom', '!=', 'BB')->orWhereNull('custom');
    })->sum('amount')
    ->get();
```